# How to set text in a JTextArea without replacing what's there?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How would I use

```
for (int j = 0; j < song.size(); j++)  {
    outputBox.setText(j + ": " + song.get(j));
}
```

To display all the items in an array, rather than replacing them as it goes and leaving the last one? Using java.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `JTextArea#append`...

```
outputBox.append(j + ": " + song.get(j));
```

But you'll probably also want to include a new line character at the end

```
outputBox.append(j + ": " + song.get(j) + "/n");
```

See [`JTextArea#append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) and [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details

It may be more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` and the set the text of the text area after the fact

```
StringBuilder sb = StringBuilder(128);
for (int j = 0; j < song.size(); j++)  {
    sb.append(j).
       append(":").
       append(song.get(j)).
       append("/n");
}
outputBox.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: @SpencerSalomons If you want to use this in a loop, then create the `StringBuilder` outside the loop, append all the text to the `StringBuilder` in the loop, and eventually, after the loop append the `StringBuilder.toString()` to the textarea. Recreating a new `StringBuilder` in every iteration is useless as this unefficient and is what the java compiler does anyway when using the `+` operator on `String`.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Good advice, but I was under the impression that Java didn't optimise `String` concatenation within loops, or is that to do with concatenating a `String` defined outside the loop?

Comment: @MadProgrammer When you use String concatenation with the `+` operator (something like `a + b`, where a and b are `String`), the compiler nicely does `new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString()` for you. Of course, in a loop, this becomes awfully unefficient, because you keep on recreating `StringBuilder` and `String`, while the `StringBuilder` could be re-used through every iteration of the loop and create only a single `String` at the end. This is also explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/928711)

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing but...

```
String oldText = outputBox.getText();
outputBox.setText(oldText + j + ": " + song.get(j));
```

Comment: This is actually really inefficient, adding the loop and it just becomes worse...

Comment: Whoever flagged: flags are not to be used to flag technically incorrect answers.

Comment: @Qix Furthermore, it's not even incorrect, just suboptimal.